# gulp inject functionality for JSP

Tags: gulp

I have the following jsp file in which there are references of  css and jss , now i want to use the gulp-inject so that dynamically css and js can be injected

I have kept css files in folder named css `C:\Softwares\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\src\main\webapp\static\css)`and my javascript files are in the folder named js `(C:\Softwares\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\src\main\webapp\static\js)`

now below is my jsp files in which i want gulp injection to be happened please advise how can i write gulp inject task that will inject the .js and .css injection dynamically

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
  <head>  
    <title>AngularJS $http Example</title>  
    <style>
   </style>

     <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/app.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" class="ng-cloak">
      <div class="generic-container" ng-controller="UserController as ctrl">

                      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/app.js' />"></script>
      <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/service/user_service.js' />"></script>
      <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/controller/user_controller.js' />"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

what I have tried is the below task

```
gulp.task('inject', function(){

var resourcesToInject =  gulp.src(
    [sourcePaths.build + 'C:\\Softwares\\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\\src\\main\\webapp\\static\\*.js'],
    {read: false});

return gulp
    .src('C:\\Softwares\\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\views\\UserManagement2.jsp')
    .pipe($.inject(
      resourcesToInject,{
            transform: transoformResourceInclude
        }
      )
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\Softwares\\Spring4MVCAngularJSExample\\src\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\views\\'));
});
```

but it is not working please advise into it

Answer (score 0):

Try below task, it will inject js dependencies from **app/client/public/js/**/*** and **app/client/public/app.js** into index.html and write the index.html into build directory

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
    gulp.task('inject-own', function() {
        gulp.src(['app/client/public/index.html'])
            .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['app/client/public/js/**/*','app/client/public/app.js'], {read: false})))            
            .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but my file extension is .jsp and not .html , please advise how to achieve the same thing for .jsp file

Comment: Did you try with .jsp, it should work as long as you have <!-- inject:js -->
      <!-- endinject --> in your JSP

Comment: So shall I put  those tags of inject js into jsp and then execute it , so inthis case I am changing my parent jsp ok I am going to try it pls and will confirm you please

Comment: And don't forget to add gulp-inject in your file, install it with npm install gulp-inject, that inject is from gulp-inject